# How to configure JNDI DataSource connection details based on different environments

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, configuration

I have a quite long JNDI connection pool defined in my context.xml. I would like to be able to reuse it with different properties (username, pw, database name) without having to keep the rest of the context.xml in sync in different environments (ide, test in ide, test while building, prod).

Putting the connection details in system properties (Tomcat should expand them in context.xml) seems to be the only real approach I have found.

Another tomcat-specific approach would be to use org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.PropertySource to return different properties based on detected environment.

Are there any easier / cleaner solutions e.g. to expand properties based on a property file?

Is it possible to configure everything except username, pw, database in context.xml and add the remaining properties somewhere in the webapp?

Comment: with maven you can do property expansion using profiles (I think). Another option is m4 on the command line that does pretty much the same stuff.

Comment: @froderik Yes, but this adds another layer of complexity while running in an ide, because it usually doesnt trigger a maven build when starting for development

Comment: aha - you want to run from the IDE. As well as in production? Maybe clarify in the question?